# Different ways to prove a set is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

I was given the theorem

> The solution set of a homogeneous system is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, called the solution space

and I was told to prove it in at least 2 different ways.  I know one way to prove it is through the subspace test, but I'm having trouble thinking about another way to prove this theorem

Comment: A subspace of what?

Comment: My bad, edited.

Comment: The kernel and range of a linear operator are linear subspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Either way you would invoke subspace test, but it might be just deeply buried. Here is one way I can think of. Let's $A$ be a matrix $m\times n$ and equations $Ax=0$ have $k$ free variables. Each solution then is defined by the set of $k$ numbers. Thus, the solution is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$. We know that $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus the solution is a subspace in the space of all vectors. But I am basically deferring the subspace test (for $\mathbb{R}^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: Unfortunately you have used some terminology that I haven't learned yet (isomorphic), but I was wondering if this would work.

Since the solution set contains vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, then the span of those vectors would be a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: @AlexTwin Isomorphism is one-to-one mapping between the sets that also preserve some operations. In case of linear sets: it preserves the addition and multiplication by a number. In general, isomorphism allows to talk about arithmetic space $\mathbb{R}^n$ in place of a general $V^n$ by fixing the basis in the latter and considering only vector coordinates.